# R Plot Auto-View

Tags: r, sublimetext3

I'm trying to figure a way to automatically open the pdf-output of an R script after i run it. My goal is to integrate that into Sublime Text (under osx) to make something like an automatic viewer for my generated plots.

Any idea is welcome (obviously if there exists a plugin that already acts as a viewer for R, much better)

Comment: What about using R to make a call to `system()`, to do a command line opening of the figure?

Comment: Thought about it, add a last line in the script that calls skim or preview to pipe the pdf to it, but still wanna know if there is a system a bit more 'native' in r (or in sublime)